# 'react-native run-ios' hangs on "Loading dependency graph, done" on first load only

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm running a React Native app, and I find when I fire up my machine for the first time and run `react-native run-ios`, it hangs on "Loading dependency graph, done" as shown in the screenshot below. I've read a number of other posts where people have had this problem, but the difference here is that it does this only the first time I run `react-native run-ios` during the given session.

If I close the windows and run it again everything works fine. I just want to understand what could be causing it to hang, just for my own knowledge. Does anyone have any insight, or can point me to some background reading I can do to be able to understand bugs like this in the future?

[image]

Comment: It is supposed hang there until the app on your device or simulator loads the first bundle. Do you mean that the JS Bundle does not load?